# How to implement auto renewable on/off feature for IAP subscription in amazon - kindle android application

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, kindle-fire

I am working on implementing subscription using `Amazon IAP version 2`. I am referring to the sample subscription application provided by them, for implementation.

I want to provide auto-renewable on/off feature for subscription in my application. So that user can turn on/off the renewing of subscription from app only and he/she does not have to go out of application. Could anyone please tell me how to do it? Which methods/apis to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible at the moment even with `Amazon IAP version 2.` I had raised the same question on [Amazon developer forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=86). The thread and conversation can be found [here](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=3711&tstart=0).

The reply I got from them is :

> Unfortunately, there is no API exposed to enable or disable auto renew
>   for a subscription. By default, auto renew is enabled and only user
>   can change it form manage subscription part in his account settings.

Thanks.